# Expand/collapse table rows in Angular

Tags: angular, html-table

The table requires that a table nested to each row can be displayed. Can only be **collapsed when selecting in the same row**.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header-row">
      <th class="header">Province</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-row-expanded" *ngFor="let covenant of covenants; let i = index">
    <tr class="table-row-not-expanded">
      <td class="cell" (click)="selectItemCoverages(i)"> {{ covenant.provinceID }}
        <ng-container *ngIf="openCoverages && indexSelectedCoverage === i">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr class="header-row">
                <th class="header">header 1</th>
                <th class="header">header 2</th>
                <th class="header">header 3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="table-row">
                <td class="cell">1</td>
                <td class="cell">2</td>
                <td class="cell">3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </tdr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Component:

```js
selectItemCoverages(index: number) {
  this.openCoverages = this.openCoverages && this.indexSelectedCoverage === index ? false : true;
  this.indexSelectedCoverage = index;
}
```

The logic problem is to control that selecting in another row (different) does not close the previous one.

Comment: I dont see any issue in logic. its working fine see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5jie4b)

Comment: This HTML is completely invalid. You can't intermix div tags into a table.

Comment: @NimittShah selecting in another row close the previous one, it should not close it. Only close if you click on the same row.

Comment: If you just need to iterate over data inside a table, you can use ng-container, which will not add an additional tag. Moreover, if you're adding a nested table, it must appear inside of a `td` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For keeping the table row expanded until you click on the row to collapse, you just need boolean flag on each element array. I would suggest to create property under your array as false and set it to toggle on click of row. Also, as @brandon mentioned in comment, your html is invalid. So I modified it a bit.

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr class="header-row">
    <th class="header">Province</th>
  </tr>
  <tr
    class="table-row-not-expanded"
    *ngFor="let covenant of covenants; let i = index"
  >
    <td class="cell" (click)="covenant.isExpanded = !covenant.isExpanded">
      <div>{{ covenant.provinceID }}</div>

      <div *ngIf="covenant.isExpanded" class="expanded-panel">
        <div class="table-container">
          <table class="table">
            <tr class="header-row">
              <th class="header">header 1</th>
              <th class="header">header 2</th>
              <th class="header">header 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table-row">
              <td class="cell">1</td>
              <td class="cell">2</td>
              <td class="cell">3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  covenants: any = [
    { provinceID: 1 },
    { provinceID: 2 },
    { provinceID: 3 },
    { provinceID: 4 },
    { provinceID: 5 },
  ];

  openCoverages = false;
  indexSelectedCoverage = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.covenants.forEach((_covenants) => {
      _covenants.isExpanded = false;
    });
  }
  selectItemCoverages(index: number) {
    //this.openCoverages = this.openCoverages && this.indexSelectedCoverage === index ? false : true;
    //this.indexSelectedCoverage = index;
  }
}
```

[Play here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5jie4b)